# Select closest to average in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to find the closest car by car price to the average car price in a table, but the following gives me an error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

```
select *
            from 
              (
                select *, abs(CAR_PRICE - (select avg(CAR_PRICE) from USER.CAR)) as PriceDif
                from USER.CAR
                order by PriceDif
              )
            where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: You may use `*` unqualified, as you have, but only if you are not also adding other columns. If you are (as you are, in the inner query), you must qualify the `*`, as in `USER.CAR.*` In the inner query, after Oracle reads `select *` it expects `from`, not a comma. Try again with `select USER.CAR.*, abs(.....)`

Comment: Specifying as CAR.* in the inner query gave me an error: `invalid character`

Comment: ?? Which invalid character? The error message should give you the line and position where the error occurs. (Or is this a RUNTIME error - in which case you may have bad data?) In any case - I show how this SHOULD run on a good table, using a standard Oracle schema and table.

Comment: Okay this is sort of odd. I'm running this in coldfusion and got that error, but when i run it in Oracle SQL developer, it returns results as it should. As it turns out, it doesn't like the `;` at the end, so your solution was correct.

Comment: Oh, understood. You may like to know that the `;` is **not** SQL. SQL statements do not end in a `;`. It is only the front-end, like SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer, that uses `;` as a marker for the end of a SQL statement. I don't know coldfusion, but it may use a different mechanism (perhaps a blank line after the end of a statement, rather than `;`?)

Comment: I didn't know that. Coldfusion uses blank, I always assumed SQL ended in ; sort of like c#

Comment: That's what I thought too - incorrectly. The issue has been discussed many times, both here and on OTN. SQL (the Standard itself) does not have a statement terminator, and for a good reason: there is no such thing as a "block" of statements. Each SQL statement is stand-alone, and the database receives them and processes them one at a time. Anything that looks different is not actually SQL - it may be a script, or whatever, but SQL itself is stand-alone statements, which don't need to be separated or terminated.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg: in SQL the semi-colon is a statement terminator which is really only used (in the standard grammar, anyways) when setting up embedded SQL statements. See [this link to the SQL-92 grammar](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf). (PL/SQL, which can be thought of as "Ada with embedded SQL", used the semicolon as its statement terminator because A) Ada does, and B) it sort of fits in with the "embedded SQL" thing). So if you have a stand-alone SQL statement, such as a `SELECT` you're passing to some sort of API for execution, a semicolon should never be necessary. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `*` unqualified, as you have, but only if you are not also adding other columns. If you are (as you are, in the inner query), you must qualify the `*`, as in `USER.CAR.*` In the inner query, after Oracle reads `select *` it expects `from`, not a comma. Try again with `select USER.CAR.*, abs(.....)`

**Proof of concept** (running this from a different schema, referencing the standard SCOTT schema)

```
select *
from   ( select scott.emp.*, abs(sal - (select avg(sal) from scott.emp)) as sal_diff 
         from   scott.emp
         order by sal_diff
       )
where rownum = 1
;

EMPNO ENAME JOB      MGR  HIREDATE   SAL COMM DEPTNO SAL_DIFF
 7782 CLARK MANAGER 7839 06-09-1981 2450          10 376.78571
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic function to get rid of the nested sub-query and only need to perform a single table scan:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT e.*,
           AVG( salary ) OVER () AS avg_salary
    FROM HR.Employees e
  )
  ORDER BY ABS( salary - avg_salary )
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

*(Example using Oracle's HR schema)*